# How to control X Axis labels in Google Visualization API?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

There are (too) many labels on the X axis, and they are displayed as '8/...'. They are supposed to be dates (8/22/2011), but since there are too many, they are replaced by ellipsis.

How do you reduce the number of labels so that the dates show up properly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To show every 4th label: `hAxis: {showTextEvery: 4}`

To show a total of (about) 4 labels: `var showEvery = parseInt(data.getNumberOfRows() / 4);`

Thanks to http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/ for the answer.